# Woocommerce Categories Limit

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was wondering how to put limit on wordpress woocommerce categories display. I want to display only top 3 categories but this code is showing all categories. i do not want to display water polo category

```
 `<?php
    $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
    $orderby      = '';  
    $show_count   = 0;     
    $pad_counts   = 0;     
    $hierarchical = 1;     
    $title        = '';  
    $empty        = 0;
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
        'orderby'      => $orderby,
        'show_count'   => $show_count,
        'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
        'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
        'title_li'     => $title,
        'hide_empty'   => $empty,
    );
    $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
    foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
        if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
            $category_id = $cat->term_id;
            $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
            ?>`
```

I want to show only 3 categories on home page (any of them randomly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add number parameter  to limit category .

```
'number'       => 3,
```

Your full code

```
<?php
    $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
    $orderby      = '';  
    $show_count   = 0;     
    $pad_counts   = 0;     
    $hierarchical = 1;     
    $title        = '';  
    $empty        = 0;
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
        'orderby'      => $orderby,
        'show_count'   => $show_count,
        'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
        'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
        'title_li'     => $title,
        'hide_empty'   => $empty,
        'number'       => 3,
    );
    $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
    foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
        if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
            $category_id = $cat->term_id;
            $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
?>
```